# Search for Multiple Sublists of Same List in Python

Tags: python, list, sublist

I need Python to search all the sublists of a given list, but this does not work when I'm searching for an element contained in only one of them. For example, this is my code:

```
data = [[4,5],[4,7]]
search = 4
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print("there", sublist)

    else:
        print("not there")
        print(data)
```

and this works very well if my search is contained in all of the sublists of the lists. However, if my search is, for instance, 5, then I get:

```
there [4,5] #I only want this part. 
not there # I don't want the rest. 
[[4, 5], [4, 7]]
```

EDIT: 
Basically, I need Python to list all the lists the search is contained in, but if the search is only contained in one sublist, I only want the `print("there", sublist)`. In other words, I only want Python to recognize the places the search is in, and not output where it is not, so no `print("not there") print(data)`.

Comment: You need to clarify what your expected output is.  What if it is in two of the three sublists?  Do you expect your search to stop at the first one, or...?

Comment: I agree with roippi, your question is really confusing. It seems like a simple break after `print("there", sublist)` is what you're looking for, but I'm unsure because I don't know what you really want.

Comment: it's quite clear to me, which answer should be exactly what @tcaswell had answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a boolean tag. For example:

```
data = [[4,5],[4,7]]
search = 5
found = false
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print("there", sublist)
        found = true
if found == false:
    print("not there")
    print(data)
```

This way the print data is outside the for loop and won't be printed each time a sublist is found that does not contain search.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [[4,5],[4,7]]
search = 4
found_flag = False
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print("there", sublist)
        found_flag = True

#     else:
#        print("not there")
#        print(data)
if not found_flag:
    print('not found')
```

There is no reason to include the `else` clause if you don't want to do anything with the sub-lists that don't include the search value.

A nifty use of `else` is after the `for` block (but this only will find one entry) ([doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)):

```
data = [[4,5],[4,7]]
search = 4
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print("there", sublist)
        break
else:
    print 'not there'
```

which will execute the `else` block if it makes it through the whole loop with out hitting a `break`.

Comment: This should be what OP wants.

Comment: I quite like this answer; however, could it be expanded so that if the search is included in multiple sublists, all of them are printed instead of only the first, chronologically?

Comment: see @user2255137 's answer on how to add a flag to this loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you were probably trying to write:

```
data = [[4,5],[4,7]]
search = 4
found = False
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        found = True
        break
# do something based on found
```

A better way to write that:

```
any(search in sublist for sublist in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print("there", sublist)
        break
    else:
        print("not there")

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > data = [[4,5],[4,7],[5,6],[4,5]]
> > >
> > > search = 5
> > >
> > > for sublist in data:

```
if search in sublist:

    print "there in ",sublist

else:
    print "not there in " , sublist
```

there in  [4, 5]

not there in  [4, 7]

there in  [5, 6]

there in  [4, 5]

I just tried your code, and i am not seeing anything wrong while searching 5