# Search for Two Elements of a Sublist with Either or Two or Three Elements

Tags: python, list, sublist

I am trying to write a code so that the search will return any sublist in which both of the 2 elements of the search are the first two elements of the list. Basically I want if I have

```
data = [[4,3,0],[4,7], [6,3], [9,2], [4,3]]
search = 4,3
```

to return

```
there [4,3,0]
there [4,3]
```

Currently, I have

```
search = [4,3]
data = [[4,3,0],[4,7], [6,3], [9,2], [4,3]]
if search in data:
    print("there", search)
else:
    print("not there")
```

but this only returns

```
there [4,3]
```

EDIT: I also need to be able to append the sublists in which the search is contained.

Thanks for any help. 
Cheers! 5813

Comment: Okay seriously you keep asking this same question only slightly changed each time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128342/search-for-multiple-sublists-of-same-list-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149273/search-for-multiple-elements-in-same-sublist-of-list

Comment: When I add in a comment or thread, that I was looking for a slightly tweaked answer I am told to start a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a modified version of alok's method where I replaced his "d" with "sublist" so I could later print and append it. Thanks for all the help!

```
search = [4,3]
data = [[4,3,0],[4,7], [6,3], [9,2], [4,3]]

for sublist in data:
    if search == sublist[:len(search)]:
        sublist.append("c")
        print("there", sublist)
```

which returns exactly what I want:

```
there [4,3,0,'c']
there [4,3,'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop to loop through each sub-list and Python array slicing to compare just the first two items from the list you are searching.

```
search = [4,3]
data = [[4,3,0],[4,7], [6,3], [9,2], [4,3]]

for d in data:
    if search == d[:len(search)]:
        print("there", search)
    else:
        print("not there")
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is:

```
search = [4,3]
data = [[4,3,0],[4,7], [6,3], [9,2], [4,3]]    
sublist = []

flag = False
for x in data:
    flag = True
    for v in search:
        if v not in x:
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        sublist.append(x)

print "sublist : ", sublist
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful answer, but is there a way to append the sublist so that the appendage is inside of the brackets of the sublists in which the search is contained? Thanks again.